# Need to extract Dictionary from an Object of Type ArrayList

Tags: c#

I have a Dictionary.
It has 3 keys:**kind**, **Id**, and **items**.
Value of **items** is an Object of type ArrayList which contains a Dictionary inside.
How to extract this Dictionary which is inside the object of Type ArrayList[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7rov.png)

Similary, that inner Dictionary has keys:**kind**, **id**, **etag**, **selflink**, **volumeInfo**.
Out of these, the value of **volumeInfo** again consist of an object of Type ArrayList which contains a Dictionary.

I need to extract values of **title**, **subtitle**, authors from the most inner Dictionary of volumeInfo

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. You need to add your code. A description of what you are doing is not enough.

Comment: I would recommend you to use custom types (classes). Much easier to handle than thousands of dictionaries.

Comment: What is the question? How to determine the type of each object? Have you tried checking the types with `as` or `is`? Or the `OfType<>` LINQ operator? It's very hard to help with such a vague question. One would have to *reverse engineer* the actual code in order to modify it.

Comment: See marked duplicate. You just need to cast to the type you are retrieving. Your scenario looks almost identical to the JSON scenario in the marked duplicate. If your doing JSON deserialization, it's exactly the same and even if you aren't, it's still basically exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

Any element in your `Dictionary` and `ArrayList` are *treated* as `object`, which means the compiler doesn't know about the actual type. To use one of these elements, you'll have to cast it:

```
ArrayList list = (ArrayList)dict["items"];
```

However, if the dictionary does not contain an `"items"` key, or if the value for the `"items"` key is not an `ArrayList`, this code will throw an exception. If you know the contents of your data structure are always the same, this doesn't need to be a problem.

You can test whether the dictionary contains a certain entry:

```
object o;
if (!dict.TryGetValue("items", out o))
{
    // item not found!
}
```

And then test - and cast - the element:

```
ArrayList items = o as ArrayList;
if (items == null)
{
    // items is not an ArrayList!
}
```

Accessing the `ArrayList` is similar regarding the casting bit.

Your data would be much easier to access (and simpler to code around) when you create an object that has "Kind", "TotalItems" and "Items" properties. Even if this data structure is the result of Json or Xml deserialization, there are serializers that can deserialize into dedicated classes.